# How to get the protocol of request with esi

Tags: http, http-headers, request, akamai, esi

Title says it all, I'm wondering how you can access the protocol (http vs https) with ESI. Not finding anything in the developer's guide (http://www.akamai.com/dl/technical_publications/akamai_esi_developers_guide.pdf) or on their example pages.

Anyone have experience looking at the protocol, or at least the url with ESI?

Comment: can someone help as on this? we are also stuck on the same

Comment: @a4arpan I guess I could add this in as an answer, but basically my team spoke with akamai and they added in a feature specifically for our request, and it looks like:

    `$(SCHEME)`

you would probably need to speak with someone at akamai as we did. But it couldn't hurt to see if that works for you, if it does let me know and one of us can add it as the answer

Comment: you are a life saver man. thanks a lot.

Comment: @a4arpan it worked for you?

Comment: No it's not working for us

Comment: @a4arpan ... I'm confused -- why am I a lifesaver then?

Comment: I tested after posting that :(

Comment: @a4arpan gotcha. Well you should send Akamai an email then requesting this feature, I would imagine they would eventually add this feature into the ESI language, but that won't happen unless it's requested by more people

Comment: Can anyone please let me know the email address on which the email should be sent.